# Ksoap2 forming SoapObject

Tags: ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I need to generate a SoapObject. here is my code --

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method);
SoapObject r = new SoapObject(namespace, "request");
r.addProperty("email", email);      
request.addSoapObject(r);
```

my code generates the following

```
   <Info xmlns=NAMESPACE > 
      <request>
     <email>id@gmail.com</email>
      </request>
   </Info>
```

but the request body needs to be like this

```
<con:Info>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <con:request>

        <typ:email>id@gmail.com</typ:email>

     </con:request>
  </con:Info>
```

what should i do to include that typ:'s equivalent in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want to generate lacks namespace declarations, they are probably somewhere up in the tree.

The namespace for email seems to be different than the namespace for the rest. Your code needs to reflect that to generate equivalent XML.

p.s. You could try something like

```
PropertyInfo emailType = new PropertyInfo();
emailType.name = "email";
emailType.namespace = emailNamespace;
emailType.type = String.class;
r.addProperty(emailType, email);
```

kSOAP was written for J2ME, which does not support reflection, and it has some complexities to work around this. I don' think I can really recommend it on Android:

- For simple cases, one could just use the DOM
- For complex cases, a serialization library similar to GSON might make more sense (not sure if something similar to GSON exists for SOAP object serialization).

Comment: its not getting the email field.. any idea on what would be equivalent to that typ: in ksoap2??

Comment: Hm, I think the problem might be that you can't set a different namespace for primitive properties in kSOAP. So kSOAP might just not work for your application. What is the value of the variable "method" in your code example?

Comment: it contains the method name e.g. getInfo